# Button event Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, tkinter, button

Можно ли сделать и если можно то как, чтобы из **`1`** и **`2`** полей можно было найти и показать в **`3`** поле одинаковые слова по нажатию кнопки.

Я сделал вот это, а далее пока не знаю как это сделать.

```
from tkinter import *
 
 
window = Tk()
window.title("WINDOW")
window.geometry('265x180')
 
lbl = Label(window, text="1:")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
txt = Entry(window, width = 50)
txt.grid(column=0, row=1)
txt.insert(0, "Default Text")
 
 
lb2 = Label(window, text="2:")
lb2.grid(column=0, row=50)
txt2 = Entry(window, width = 50)
txt2.grid(column=0, row=100)
txt2.insert(0, "Default Text1")
 
 
lb3 = Label(window, text="3:")
lb3.grid(column=0, row=150)
txt3 = Entry(window, width = 50)
txt3.grid(column=0, row=200)
 
 
btn = Button(window, text="Search")  
btn.grid(column=0, row=250)
 
    
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
def func():
    list_1 = txt.get().split()
    list_2 = txt2.get().split()
    c = ' '.join(list(set(list_1) & set(list_2)))
    txt3.delete(0, "end")
    txt3.insert(0, c)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 
window = Tk()
window.title("WINDOW")
window.geometry('265x180')
 
lbl = Label(window, text="1:")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
txt = Entry(window, width = 50)
txt.grid(column=0, row=1)
txt.insert(0, "Default Text")
 
 
lb2 = Label(window, text="2:")
lb2.grid(column=0, row=50)
txt2 = Entry(window, width = 50)
txt2.grid(column=0, row=100)
txt2.insert(0, "Default Text1")
 
 
lb3 = Label(window, text="3:")
lb3.grid(column=0, row=150)
txt3 = Entry(window, width = 50)
txt3.grid(column=0, row=200)
 
# +++                               vvvvvvvvvvvv
btn = Button(window, text="Search", command=func)       # +++
btn.grid(column=0, row=250)
 
    
window.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]